# biztalk server ftp file transfer success / failure acknowledgement

Tags: transactions, ftp, biztalk

hey guys i am a newbie when it comes to biztalk

how do i enable a file by file ftp transfer job on biztalk where biztalk acknowledges for every file transfer whether it was a success or failure

i also need to update my db with boolean values for each file (1 for success, 0 for failure)

so how can i enable some sort of transaction with biztalk where either both (ftp + db) is successful or both fail...

Answer (score 1):

Raj,

I would take a look at using ACKs and NACKs as a way to guarantee delivery in BizTalk.  Here's a great starting [point](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/biztalkgeneral/thread/3d741180-ed65-4a1f-b184-f0a5bc091930).  Also look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/kevinsmi/archive/2004/07/03/172574.aspx).